# Make a MyBB Thread In PHP

Tags: php, api, mybb

I have researched this topic and there is no documentation on it.

It should be pretty easy to solve for someone who knows their way around PHP.

Essentially I own a forum.

I want to be able to make threads on my forum under my forum username from other PHP scripts that I code.

For example I want a simple API that I can use the following in my custom coded scripts:

```
make_thread($threadtitle, $threadbody);
```

That's all I want.

Should be simple,

Comment: See this http://community.mybb.com/thread-121792-post-881836.html#pid881836

Comment: That's a very out dated resource, I am looking for resource compatible with 1.8.x

Comment: Thank you for the link though

Answer (score 1):

Here is the method I coded myself

```
function makethread($subject, $thread) {

$host="***"; // Host name
$username="***"; // Mysql username
$password="***"; // Mysql password
$db_name="***"; // Database name


mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");

$ridtid = rand(111111,999999);

$time = time();
$q1 = "INSERT into mybb_posts (tid, fid, subject, icon, uid, username, message, visible) VALUES('$ridtid', '7', '$subject', '6', '1', 'Nick', '$thread', '1')";
$q2 = "INSERT into mybb_threads (tid, fid, subject, icon, uid, username, dateline, lastpost, lastposter, visible) VALUES('$ridtid', '7', '$subject', '6', '1', 'Nick', '$time', '$time', 'Nick', '1')";
$q3 = "UPDATE mybb_forums SET lastposttid='$ridtid' WHERE fid='7'";
$q4 = "UPDATE mybb_forums SET lastpost='$time' WHERE fid='7'";
mysql_query($q1);
mysql_query($q2);
mysql_query($q3);
mysql_query($q4);

 }
```

Comment: thanks for sharing; it can be improved but good to know it is possible